# Different renders of RGB data in scipy vs pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colors, scipy

I'm implementing a fractal-flame renderer for kicks and giggles, and got hung up on a silly little color problem. After running the algorithm, I get a RGBA matrix (HxWxC, specifically I have 1080x1440x4), but I get different results when rendering it with pyplot than I do with scipy. Here's the output code:

```
condensed = prepare_image(condensed, **condensed_args)
condensed[np.isnan(condensed)] = 0
name += '.png' if not name.endswith('.png') else ''
sc.misc.imsave("sc_" + name, condensed, format='png')
plt.imsave("pl_" + name, condensed)
```

And here's the two output images:

Scipy:
[image: Scipy's output image]

Pyplot:
[image: Pyplot's output image]

Ignoring the background color (the alpha there is 0, so I can deal with that manually), the details are totally different in color: scipy produces a smooth cyan'ish color, whereas pyplot produces a static'y hodgepodge of random colors. If I load scipy's image back in with pyplot.imread and display it, I get the nice cyan, so there must be something with how pyplot is interpreting my original RGBA matrix. I'm not setting any color map or index anywhere else that I can see. The documentation for both imsave functions seem to say they behave the same way (and pyplot's imshow behaves the same as its imsave, as should be expected).

If I had to guess, it looks like pyplot is interpreting my data as HSL, or some other color space. The Scipy one is closer to what I'm expecting, and what the algorithm is supposed to produce.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saving a floating point array, `scipy.misc.imsave()` (which uses Pillow to do the actual work) effectively scales the values in the array to the interval [0, 1].  `plt.imsave()`, on the other hand, appears to *clip* the values to the interval [0, 1], without changing the values that are within [0, 1].

If you transform the values in `condensed` to the interval [0, 1] with something like

```
condensed = (condensed - condensed.min())/condensed.ptp()
```

before saving the image using `plt.imsave()`, it should produce the same image as `scipy.misc.imsave()`.